# Error while compiling openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to compile a basic OpenCV program but having some strange errors.

```
$ g++ -o Read_and_write Read_and_write.cpp `pkg-config opencv --cflags 
--libs`
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5OpenGL
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5Concurrent
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5Test
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5Widgets
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5Gui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lQt5Core
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

The program is mentioned below.

```
#include </usr/include/opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include </usr/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main( )
{

       Mat image;

       // LOAD image
       image = imread("image1.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);   // Read the file "image.jpg".
              //This file "image.jpg" should be in the project folder.
              //Else provide full address : "D:/images/image.jpg"

       if(! image.data )  // Check for invalid input
       {
              cout <<  "Could not open or find the image" << std::endl ;
              return -1;
       }

       //DISPLAY image
       namedWindow( "window", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); // Create a window for display.
       imshow( "window", image ); // Show our image inside it.

       //SAVE image
       imwrite("result.jpg",image);// it will store the image in name "result.jpg"

       waitKey(0);                       // Wait for a keystroke in the window
       return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why is Qt involved. I recently removed conda from the system.

UPDATE:
I used these flags to successfully run the program but I still have the doubts.

```
-lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_objdetect
```

Comment: `-DWITH_QT=OFF` pass this flag to CMake.

Comment: With only this flag, getting undefined reference error for cv objects.

Comment: No I didn't mean to compile your own code with this flag. I meant compile OpenCV with this flag. Did you build OpenCV from source or install from repo?

Comment: I built it. Also, while compiling the program earlier, the Qt so errors were generated from anaconda directory.

Comment: Go to your opencv build folder. In terminal run `cmake .. >> result.txt`. Post the file here.

Comment: I can't find a build folder. I am not sure if I built it or installed it. What else can work?

Comment: If you don't know whether you built or installed it, then you need to read a tutorial on how to properly configure OpenCV on your machine.